# Camera advice: Sony A5000?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, digital, compact-cameras

Thinking of buying a compact camera that can make good quality shots. Does the Sony A5000 represent a good value? Or I can find better for the money?

Comment: This question is VERY general. 
The answer to this question cannot be other than subjective. 
What are the features you are looking for in a camera?
Please check [Help center](http://photo.stackexchange.com/help/asking) for guides on how to write a question.

Answer (score 3):

A few thoughts :

> Thinking of buying a compact camera that can make good quality shots.

There's an old saying ( which is true ) that good photographers take good photos, cameras don't.  Learning technique is very important.

> Does the Sony A5000 represent a good value ?

This rather depends on you.  It's wasted if you just expect the camera to take better shots without you learning to "drive" it.  This is no different that driving a car - a better car does not make a better driver.

> Or I can find better for the money?

Used cameras are better value.  Older does not mean significantly less capable.

I would suggest you consider three things :

- Do you need a viewfinder ?  I would be loath to buy any camera without a viewfinder and I often see people suggest that once they get used to a viewfinder they'd never shoot without one.
- Will a cheaper basic compact or smatphone do the job ?  People often have expectations of new camera equipment which are unrealistic.  You need to establish your expectations and work out how much of those can be met, and how much depend on technique.  A surprising amount can be done with modest equipment and the right technique.
- Flash.  Many beginners try to avoid flash, when a more experienced photographer would automatically try to use it.  Again this is technique and also, to some extent, acknowledging the need to *add light*.  I have the not dissimilar Sony NEX F3, and I would generally employ flash more often than many less experienced photographers simply because I know I need to to get the result I want.

Comment: This one really nails it as a good answer on this generic question.